# I was testing argv import in python and there is an error

Tags: python

I was reading "Learn Python 3 the Hard Way" and was testing the 'from sys import argv' there is an error occuring here is the sample code of the book:

```
from sys import argv
first, second, third = argv

print("The scipt is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:,", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

An I got this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:/MyCodes/PythonCodes/jon.py", line 2, in 
first, second, third = argv
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Comment: How are you calling the script?

Answer (score 0):

Argv will be an array with your commandline arguments this is trying to split the list into, first, second, third.

Use argn to know how many arguments to expect

```
from sys import argn, argv
for i in range(argn):
    print(f”arg {i}: {argv[i]}”)
```

Answer (score 0):

argv returns list of prarameter passed in command line
argv[0] = script name
argv[1] = first value passed in to program, and so on.

```
from sys import argv
script,first, second, third = argv

print("The scipt is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:,", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

For this script your command should look like this

```
python filename.py firstval secondval thirdval
```

for Variable lengthn arguments you can use `argn` as mentioned in one of the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
from sys import argv
# read the WYSS section for how to run this
script, first, second, third = argv

print("The script is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

In WWSS section(What You Should See) in first line you see what you should enter in
PowerShell. Line goes like this:

```
$ python3.6 ex13.py first 2nd 3rd
```

First thing:
You wrote your code wrong on line two: look mine to see where you have mistaken,
You are missing script variable.

Second:
What you probably entered in terminal is this:

```
$ python3.6 ex13.py
```

Notice how you should enter 3 variables that are missing.
Argv are named before running the script in the same line as the script name.

Hope this helped you!